# Count length of array of array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array and I want to count total numbers into this, can anyone please let me know how can i achieve this using pure javascript

```
var total = {
    "numbers":{
        "1":"9897877884",
        "2":"9867543234",
        "3":"7898879900",
        "4":"1234567890"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an array of array. This is an object with a property that is also an object.

Comment: Ohk, so i was searching in stackoverflow about this was totally wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys(total.numbers).length`. The first part returns an array with the keys and the second gets the length of it.

```js
var total = { "numbers": { "1": "9897877884", "2": "9867543234", "3": "7898879900", "4": "1234567890" } };
console.log(Object.keys(total.numbers).length);
```

[**Object.keys()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The **`Object.keys()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

[**Array#length**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

> The **`length`** property represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.